# error in Struts framework settings

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, struts

I downloaded tomcat, eclipse, Struts framework. Tomcat is working. Where to place eclipse and Struts? I placed eclipse and Struts outside tomcat folder. The needed jar files are stored inside eclipse current folder. I'm getting error.

```
 <%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<bean:write name="helloWorldForm" property="message"/>
</body>
</html>
unknown tag:bean.write
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is an IDE. It's used to develop Java applications. Not just one application, but several ones. You shouldn't place any app-specific jar into the eclipse folder.

Struts (and not strut or struct) is a web framework. Its jars must be put in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your deployed application. In an Eclipse web project, the location for them is (typically) `<yourProjectDirectory>/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: because the struts jar is not in the webapp's classpath.